# How to create a fixed length text file in Golang?

Tags: text, go

I need to create a fixed length text file from  data in a database. The data export is no problem, and loading data into Go also works. How would I print the data in a fixed length style?

I have the following struct

```
type D struct {
  A10 string // Should be 10 characters in result file
  A20 string // Should be 20 characters in result file
  A50 string // Should be 50 characters in result file
}

var d := D{ "ten", "twenty", "fifty" }
```

So, the result of the printed struct should be

```
|       ten|              twenty|                                   fifty|
```

I already figured out, that `fmt.Printf("%10s", "ten")` will prepend up until 10 leading spaces, but I couldn't figure out how to stop it from overflowing: `fmt.Printf("%10s", "tenaaaaaaaa")` will print 11 characters.

I thought about a function which goes through every field and cuts out too long strings:

```
func trimTooLong(d *D) {
  d.A10 = d.A10[:10]
  d.A20 = d.A20[:20]
  d.A50 = d.A20[:50]
}
```

Would there be a better approach?

Comment: Side note, you want to exclude the `var` when declaring `d` variable. Should look like `d := D{"ten", "twenty", "fifty"}`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the precision in the string format to truncate the output as the field width.

```
fmt.Printf("%5.5s", "Hello, world")
fmt.Printf("%5.5s", "A")
```

will output `"Hello    A"`.

So in your example, this will do the trick:

```
fmt.Printf("%10.10s%20.20s%50.50s", d.A10, d.A20, d.A50)
```

Comment: This is the most suitable way so far, since I can also pad "0" like `fmt.Printf("%05.5", "12")`

Answer (score 0):

I think that your method is fine. You could also use the [`TextMarhsaler`](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/#TextMarshaler) or the [`Stringer`](http://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Stringer) interface to do it more cleanly than with a function.

Comment: It's not fine in that it panics on strings shorter specified.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is fine really, but IMO you should rethink your goal with that code.

A clean way to implement it without TextMarshaler or String is using something like:

```
func writeTrimmed(w io.Writer, in []*D) error {
    for _, d := range in {
        a10, a20, a50 := d.A10, d.A20, d.A50
        if len(a10) > 10 {
            a10 = a10[:10]
        }
        if len(a20) > 20 {
            a20 = a20[:20]
        }
        if len(a50) > 50 {
            a50 = a50[:50]
        }
        if _, err := fmt.Fprintf(w, "|%10s|%20s|%50s|\n", a10, a20, a50); err != nil {
            return err
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

[<kbd>playground</kbd>](http://play.golang.org/p/sM7ptK8nfb)